# How to prove matrix differential rules using differential forms rules

Tags: differential-forms

I am learning differential forms on my own through lectures on youtube and one of the things that I am attempting to do is to check if I can derive matrix differential rules using the rules for differential forms. i.e. Prove:

d(X+Y) = d(X) + d(Y) using the 4 differential form rules:

The 4 differential form rules being:

1. d(d(w)) = 0
2. df = $\sum_{1,n} \frac{\delta f}{\delta x_{i}} dx_{i}$
3. d(aw + bx) = ad(w) + bd(x) where w,x are 1-form
4. d(w ^ x) = d(w) ^ x + (-1)^pq w ^ d(x) where w is p-form and x is q-form

I am stuck in this proof and this probably indicates some gap in my understanding.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please include the "differential form rules" and the exact results you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to use rule 3.

If $X, Y$ are the matrices of elements $(x_{ij}), (y_{ij})$, then $X+Y$ is the matrix of elements $(x_{ij}+y_{ij})$.

Now, you have to *define* $d$ for matrices. You do it component by component. That is, the matrix $dX$ is the matrix of components $(dx_{ij})$, *by definition*.

Now, using our expression for the sum of matrices:
$$
d(X+Y) = d(x_{ij}+y_{ij}).
$$

Using our definition of $d$ for matrices:
$$
d(x_{ij}+y_{ij}) = (d(x_{ij}+y_{ij})).
$$

Using rule 3:
$$
(d(x_{ij}+y_{ij})) = (dx_{ij}+dy_{ij}).
$$

Re-using our expression for the sum:
$$
(dx_{ij}+dy_{ij}) = (dx_{ij}) + (dy_{ij}),
$$

which are the matrices (using again our definition for $d$):
$$
(dx_{ij}) + (dy_{ij}) = dX + dY.
$$